# DESCRIBE table returns nothing

Tags: parquet, apache-drill

According to [docs](https://drill.apache.org/docs/describe/), this command should return table structure:

```sql
DESCRIBE schema.<table>
```

I tried:

```sql
-- Some CSV of 1000 lines (csv.extract_header=true)
DESCRIBE dfs.`sample_data.csv`
-- Empty result

-- Output format set to parquet
CREATE TABLE dfs.tmp.`test_parquet` AS SELECT * FROM dfs.`sample_data.csv`
-- > 1000 rows created 

-- Querying newly created table
DESCRIBE dfs.tmp.`test_parquet`
-- Empty result

-- Querying my own parquet from somewhere else
DESCRIBE dfs.`another.parquet`
-- Empty result

REFRESH TABLE METADATA dfs.tmp.`test_parquet`
DESCRIBE dfs.tmp.`test_parquet`
-- Empty result

-- I've got postgres datasource connected as "pg"
DESCRIBE pg.public.MyPostgresTable
-- > Returns valid structure
```

It seems that `DESCRIBE` command does not describe parquets and CSV.

What I'm missing?

Drill v1.15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [docs](https://drill.apache.org/docs/describe/#describe), this command may be used for views created in a workspace, tables created in Hive and HBase, or schemas.
`DESCRIBE` does not support tables created in a file system.